# Are protobuf messages compatible across versions of protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, backwards-compatibility

I started building an app with protobuf 2.2.0 as it was the latest. Now I'm considering upgrading to protobuf 2.4.0a which is the latest.
If I do so will the messages generated by one version of the app still be readable by the other version for the same schema? Or would I be breaking something?

Comment: For proto3 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680273/protobuf-backward-compatibility-and-proto3-vs-proto2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be fine. Version 2.1.0 introduced packed repeated fields, but I don't believe there have been any wire format changes since then.

Comment: And to emphasise (for the OP) existing messages would have been fine; backwards compatible etc

Comment: @Marc: Yup. The danger would have been writing out packed repeated fields in newer code, and expecting older code to read it. That shouldn't be a problem between 2.2 and 2.4 though, and you'd have to do it explicitly anyway.