# Data format compatibility between protobuf versions

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers

I was wondering if protocol buffer's serialized data format remains constant across protobuf compiler and client library versions.

In other words, do I need to use the same compiler version to generate my Python, Java, and C++ classes? And do these clients all need to use the same version of protobuf libraries?

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963620/are-protobuf-messages-compatible-across-versions-of-protobuf) sort of addresses my question, but its accepted answer is specific to the OP's protobuf version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is pretty much the idea. It shouldn't matter which library you use, as long as it follows the spec. Note that the same data *can* be represented in slightly different ways, for example field order should not matter to the client, and while it is *common* for clients to write fields in ascending order, it is explicitly required of clients to process fields in any order. All I'm saying here is that it might not be *exactly the same bytes in the same order*, but it should work fine from any client.

Note that some implementations might offer *additional* features (*cough* like mine offers inheritance support), intended for use primarily only within that single client. In that case, I would a: expect those features to be obvious when used, and b: it should *always* still produce a valid protobuf stream (you might just choose to ignore those fields, or support them as `bytes` for the purpose of round-trip).

Comment: if its not "exactly the same bytes in the same order", many clients will break. anyone that relies on hashing and crypto signatures.