# Is the output of Google's Protobuf TextFormat serializer stable between different versions and platforms?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, protocol-buffers

Google's Protocol Buffers implementation contains a [`TextFormat`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format) class, which is able to serialize Messages to/from text.

How stable is this text format?  Specifically:

- If I serialize a proto2 defined message to UTF8, will any other version of Google's Protocol Buffers implementation in the same language be able to deserialize it given the same proto2 message definition?
- Is this still true if we're talking about google-published implementations in different languages?

Comment: I think you question is covered by the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604929/data-format-compatibility-between-protobuf-versions?rq=1).

Comment: @petersv That's about the binary format used over the wire.  I'm asking about the text format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, protobuf "text format" is the same across all implementations. You can call `toString()` in Java and then parse it using `TextFormat` in C++, etc.

Note, however, that text format is intended for communications where one end (sender or receiver) is a human. For computer-to-computer communications, you should always use binary format. Text format has some important differences that make sense when talking to a human but not between computers:

- When an unknown field name is seen in text input, it is an error. In contrast, with binary format, unknown fields are ignored for forwards-compatibility. In text format, though, the assumption is that an unknown name is probably a typo on the part of the human, and so would be dangerous to ignore.
- Text format parsing and writing is much, much slower than binary format. It is implemented in terms of reflection interfaces rather than generated code, and it is not well-optimized.