# Can I use proto2 generated code stubs with libprotobuf3.x?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto, proto3

I have a legacy application using proto2 with libprotobuf2.x. There is another application application that I would like this application to talk to with proto3.

I checked on possible solutions and the discussion in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372047/link-two-different-version-of-protobuf-library-in-the-same-c-project)
says that libprotobuf3.x provides compatibility with proto2.

Does this mean that I can use the same proto(with proto2) and the same code stubs pb.h/pb.cpp generated for proto2 and just link my legacy application with libprotobuf3.x instead and it would work like a charm?

I don't want to update legacy protos to proto3 as it might require major refactoring in the legacy code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protobuf backward compatibility and proto3 vs proto2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680273/protobuf-backward-compatibility-and-proto3-vs-proto2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't link `.pb.*` files generated with `protoc` 2.0 against `libprotobuf` 3.0.
Just like with any shared library, an increment in the major version number means a breaking API change.

Compatibility with `proto2` means that Proto 2 *syntax* is supported (`syntax = "proto2"`). Also `proto3` is binary-compatible with `proto2` on the wire.

> I don't want to update legacy protos to proto3 as it might require major refactoring in the legacy code.

Chances are, if you re-generate your `.pb` files with `protoc` 3 and recompile, it'll work without refactoring (the default syntax is still proto2).